# I have a .csv file with ucs-2 le coding, How can i read it with python?

Tags: python, csv

csv code:

```
Car Name    ID  Owner
"Porsche 911"   "0001"  "Joe Jane Peter"
"Jag"   "0007"  "Sam"
```

Comment: Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module and [open](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open) the file with the correct [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: What did you try so far? What is your goal?

Comment: @Matthias: that only works if you are on Python 3. On Python 2, this is not so easy.

Comment: @frlan: there is a known problem with Python 2, the `csv` module and multi-byte encodings.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: That's why I linked to the Python 3 documentation.

Comment: @Matthias: yes, and the OP probably wouldn't have asked this question if they were on Python 3.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Maybe. We don't know which Python version the OP runs and that was the reason I just made a comment and didn't give an answer. I might have added "If you're on Python 3 ..."

Comment: @Matthias: the dupe I linked to provides the same answer. But without context your comment was not very helpful.